# API for editing images in Vuejs Application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please is there any good api or npm package for editing and manipulating images in Vuejs app.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this

A simple picture clipping plugin for vue:  https://github.com/xyxiao001/vue-cropper
endoc:https://github.com/xyxiao001/vue-cropper/blob/master/english.md